# Any way I can declare the event object rather than in the params of a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

is there anyways I can put the e object inside of the handleSubmit function? I already have a parameter there, and if I add the e to the params then it will give me an error depending of order of params and say "TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function" if handleSubmit=(e, priorityLevelData)=> {. .... or "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined" if handleSubmit=(priorityLevelData, e)=> {

```
    import React from "react";
    import PrioritySelector from "./PrioritySelector";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";

    class TodoForm extends React.Component {


        /*submit handler to grab input from the input references and store them
        in the "todoData" object. Then dispatches an action type and payload
        capturing the data. Then clears the input*/

        handleSubmit=(e, priorityLevelData)=> {
e.preventDefault()
            const todoTitle = this.getTodoTitle.value;
            const description = this.getDescription.value;
            const priorityLevel = priorityLevelData;
            const todoData = {
                id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
                todoTitle,
                description,
                priorityLevel,
                editing: false
            }
            this.props.dispatch({type:"ADD_TODO", todoData })
            this.getTodoTitle.value = "";
            this.getDescription.value = "";

        }





        render() {
            console.log(this.props, "TODOFORMPROPS")
            return(
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getTodoTitle=input} placeholder="Enter Todo" required/>
                        <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getDescription=input} placeholder="Enter Description" required/>
                        <PrioritySelector  getData={this.handleSubmit} />
                        <button>Add Todo</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
            priorityLevel: state
        }
    }


    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
<form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
```

You can also pass any other additional data to `handleSubmit()`, for example, `this.state`:

```
<form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e, this.state)}>
```